# What is default session in TensorFlow?

Tags: session, tensorflow, default

I am trying to understand notion of default session in TensorFlow. Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()
print(tf.get_default_session == sess)
```

returns

```
False
```

This one

```
with sess.as_default() as default_session:
    print(tf.get_default_session == default_session)
```

also returns

```
False
```

And this one

```
with sess.as_default() as default_session:
    print(tf.get_default_session == sess)
```

returns

```
False
```

What is default session then?

Comment: `tf.get_default_session` is a function. Did you omit the `()` or were you deceived by the duck typing of Python, which can compare a `tf.Session` object and a function for equality? :)

Comment: Indeed, simple typo. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one : it returns true

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()  
print(tf.get_default_session() == sess)
```

> True

Answer (score 4):

Try this one: it returns true

```
with sess.as_default() as default_session:
    print(tf.get_default_session() == default_session)
    print(tf.get_default_session() == sess)
```

> True
>
> True

In fact you should use `tf.get_default_session()` instead of `tf.get_default_session`.